# cakephp 1.2 try to login but says "You are not authorized to access that location."

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I follow the instructions of cookbook and I can register a new user, but when I try to login I receive the message "You are not authorized to access that location" like I don't have permission to access the login action.

My users controller:

```
`<?php
// app/Controller/UsersController.php
class UsersController extends AppController {


    var $name = 'Users';
    var $components = array('Auth'); // Não é necessário se declarado na sua AppController

    function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('index','view', 'registra_cliente');

        if($this->Auth->user('role') == 'admin'){
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'paineis', 'action' => 'index');
        }else{
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'produtos', 'action' => 'index');
        }

        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array(Configure::read('Routing.admin') => false, '/');

        //$this->Auth->loginError = "Ops! Combinação de nome de usuário e senha inválidos!";  
        //$this->Auth->authError = "Ops! Esta área é reservada somente para administradores da loja.";
    }

    function isAuthorized() {
        if ($this->Auth->user('role') != 'admin') {
            $this->Auth->deny('registra_admin');
        }

        if ($this->Auth->user('role') == 'admin') {
            $this->Auth->allow('registra_admin');
        }
    }

    /**
     *  O AuthComponent disponibiliza as funções necessárias para login,
     *  então você pode deixar essa função em branco.
     */
    function login() {
    }

    function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

    function registra_cliente() {
        if ($this->data) {
            if ($this->data['User']['password'] == $this->Auth->password($this->data['User']['password_confirm'])) {
                $this->data['User']['role'] = "cliente";
                $this->User->create();
                $this->User->save($this->data);
            }
        }
    }

    function registra_admin() {
        if ($this->data) {
            if ($this->data['User']['password'] == $this->Auth->password($this->data['User']['password_confirm'])) {
                $this->data['User']['role'] = "admin";
                $this->User->create();
                $this->User->save($this->data);
            }
        }
    }

}
?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try allowing the login action:

```
$this->Auth->allow('index','view', 'registra_cliente', 'login');
```